# Spring.NET WebServiceExporter and WCF

Tags: spring.net

I've modified my original question (hope that's allowed)...

I have used WCF to expose my Spring Service layer. I have created a WCF project, and for each service interface (IOrderService, ICustomerService etc) in my application, I have created an SVC file and added the appropriate config in web.config. This all works well, and Spring's dependency injection is working too.

I expect that Spring's ServiceExporter class can make the process even simpler. But what does it give me that I don't already have? Does it allow me to achieve the same thing *without* needing the WCF project? The reason I ask is that most examples I have seen also mention 'editing .svc files', which are in the WCF project.

Since the ASMX WebServiceExporter allows me to create a webservice from just my interface(s) and a bit of XML config, I was thinking ServiceExporter would be similar.

OPTIONAL: as an aside, wouldn't it be better to have just one WebServiceExporter class in Spring and have a property e.g. exportAs="WCF | ASMX"?

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I just found it. For the 1.3 docs, it's explained in this section: 30.5. Exporting POCOs as WCF Services. The class for WCF seems to be Spring.ServiceModel.ServiceExporter, which would explain why I wasn't getting any hits when searching for "WCF WebServiceExporter". I'll try it out.

Comment: Actually, I reckon I could do with a full working example. Anyone know of any good ones?

Comment: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks Marijn, I did see that but what I really want is an example showing it using the ServiceExporter being applied to a regular service class. I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to create a separate WCF project. If I find one I'll post it here.

Comment: Do I still need to have a WCF Project in my application (with an SVC file)?

Comment: Right, I've WCF-ified my app, by creating a WCF project, making an SVC file for each Service interface I want to expose as a web service. Each SVC file has "Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" in it. And I've used ChannelFactory to consume them at the client side. Everything works lovely. I think that is the more 'manual' way of doing it. But I'm glad I did it because I now have an idea of what's going on (I didn't really know anything about WCF before today to be honest). So, which bits of the work I have just done would using ServiceExporter have made easier? Thanks!

Comment: I've modified my question a bit. Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read this: 
http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0-M1/reference/html/wcf-quickstart.html

> I expect that Spring's ServiceExporter class can make the process even
>   simpler. But what does it give me that I don't already have?

well, The Host have to reference the exporter object :

```
<object id="OpcServiceHost"
type="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryObject,Spring.Services">    
<property name="TargetName" value="OpcServiceExporter" /> 
</object>
```

> Does it allow me to achieve the same thing without needing the WCF project?

Are you referring to the service interface project? if so - spring.net example shows that Spring specific implementation of the WCF interfaces is used within the server project, and are not used in an interface project of it's own. Also note that the basic WCF service interfaces (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IInstanceProvider and System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior ) are encapsulated by Spring.
The example given in the link shows that you don't need such a project, however the interface is defined within the server project.

> as an aside, wouldn't it be better to have just one WebServiceExporter class in Spring and have a property e.g. exportAs="WCF | ASMX"?

Not an option - You can, however, try to use GenerateProxy method of ServiceExporter class:
http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.2/api/net-2.0/html/topic16729.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't actually had chance to try it out but you've included some really useful info and links to the docs that I missed so thanks for your help.